# Unity UI items are slow when tested in Mobile

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Unity UI Buttons and a virtual joystick made by some images work good in the editor but too slow (slow pointer up/down and drag response) when tested in the phone (Android) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI items are too slow just when you are testing them directly from unity editor with your mobile , they will work more smoothly when you build them as an apk file then sent it to the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you haven't changed anything between using the editor and building it to the device, whatever change was made was automatic by Unity. I'm guessing that one possible thing you can try is setting the target frame rate to 60 fps. Unity runs the project in its own editor without any frame rate limits, but when built to Mobile devices only (Android / iOS), it automatically limits the frame rate to 30fps. You could override this by adding **targetframerate** in any piece of code in the project, for example:

```
void Awake() {
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
}
```

More on **targetframerate** here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your try , it didn't work but i found that the pb happens when you try the game directly from the editor to mobile , it's better when you sent the apk file to the phone.